# Show error Message when a variables doesnt meet the condition in rundeck

Tags: curl, error-handling, runtime-error, rundeck

I am calling a variable for `&partNumber=789-635`

defined Variable `$part=@option.partnumber@`,  this is the input parameter which takes a value.

```
curl --location -k --request GET 'https://myprojt.test9.abc.com/api/part/config=8594&select=parts,Action,refernceNumber&SalesID=333&partNumber=$part'
```

So when i run this using rundeck and give partNumber , it should query, if no data is found it should print `'No Data Available for PartNumber= 789-635 found'`

How to set error messages in `RunDeck`, Kindly help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create an inline script that responds with any value different to zero (error), I leave an example:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='myoption' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>659c4c28-cc0e-4059-aee7-0aa95228043a</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[# first, verify if the option if empty

MYVAR=@option.myoption@

if [ -z "$MYVAR" ]
then
      echo "No Data Available for MYOPTION"; exit 1;
else
      echo "is NOT empty, the value is $MYVAR"
fi]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>659c4c28-cc0e-4059-aee7-0aa95228043a</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W7Ej.jpg) the result if the data is not present, and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zugya.jpg) if data is present.

Comment: Thank you for your comment , But what if i have a List of Numbers. Assume a list of numbers saved in a variable. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61876513/check-if-given-numbers-saved-in-a-list-matches-the-condition-and-print-the-respe

Comment: Sure, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61878159/10426011