# Check if Given numbers saved in a list matches the condition and print the respective outputs in shell

Tags: shell, error-handling, conditional-statements, rundeck

Assume a list of numbers saved in a variable.

`Part=369,424,652` ,saved in variable as `$part=@option.partnumber@`

```
curl --location -k --request GET 'https://myprojt.test9.abc.com/api/part/config=8594&select=parts,Action,refernceNumber&SalesID=333&partNumber=$part'
```

Dynamically all numbers are variable are checked when i call the curl command.

Assume if any of the number are missing and Expected output is :

Parts Present:
parts:369, Action:new,referenceNumber:06
parts:652, Action:old,referenceNUmber:09

Parts Missing:
parts:424

Trying this shell command to run this is `RunDeck` , Kindly Help, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two list in the following way. I leave an example:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='mylist' value='494,192,111,214' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>5a067bd8-3aa4-47eb-a522-19a5d9cdd797</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>ExampleList</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "starting"</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[#!/bin/bash

# your list
VAR1=@option.mylist@

# hypotetical expected values
VAR2='494,192,111,214,999'

# for debug
echo "******************"
echo "Your list: $VAR1"
echo "Your expected values: $VAR2"
echo "******************"

Field_Separator=$IFS

# set comma as internal field separator for the string list
IFS=,

# store the missing values
a=()

# check two lists
for i in $VAR2; do
    found=
    for j in $VAR1; do
        if [ $i == $j ]; then
            found=1
            break
        fi
    done
    if [ ! $found ]; then
        a+=($i)
    fi
done

# now verify the possible missing values
if [[ -z "${a[*]}" ]]; then
   echo "All ok!"
else
  echo "missing values: ${a[*]}"
  # exit with error
  exit 1
fi

IFS=$Field_Separator]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>5a067bd8-3aa4-47eb-a522-19a5d9cdd797</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHKiJ.jpg) the result when both lists match, and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xsq4.jpg) when not match.